# How do i make sure the battery is charging in the simulation?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

Here is the schematic from "Parasitic Power Harvesting in Shoes,IEEE,1998" ,and i add a button cell battery(the blue one) to let the PZT charge  it(battery).

So i have to simulate it to make sure the PZT can really charge the battery,and if i use PCB,which thing can i use to replace that battery? because i don't think i can buy a dead battery (need to be charge) outside.And if i use computer software,like virtuoso cadence,which component can i use?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of a rechargeable button cell battery. Most rechargeable batteries need some amount of regulation to prevent damage from overcharging or over-discharging.

In this case, you might consider using a super-capacitor. The only regulation you need to worry about with a supercapacitor is not charging it past its rated voltage. Supercapacitors have a lower capacity for a given size, but I doubt you'll be making much power, so the low capacity won't be a problem. [Here's a cheap 5.5-volt supercap (Digi-Key)](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/illinois-capacitor/DGH155Q5R5/1572-1772-ND/7387513)

I recommend putting it where C4 is because that's on the 5-volt regulated output of the Max666. I haven't looked very carefully, but I believe that would keep it safe from overcharging.